# Referencing objects through a tcp/ip connection - for robotics

Tags: c#, tcp, robotics

I've begun to design a framework for a robot I'm going to build. The control-software is - for reasons of later portability and also for the challenge herein - an attempt at mimicking the human system (of course drastically simplified). Thus the framework has a nervous system, consisting of a brain and spinal cord, the latter through which the brain controls the sensors and 'limbs' of the peripheral nervous system - i.e. the robots camera, microphones, motorcontrols and so on.

My challenge is in that I can't figure out how to send commands from the brain - via the spinal cord - to the sensor objects, initialized by the peripheral nervous system controller. In my implementation, the spinal cord is a tcp/ip server, accepting connections from the sensors and sending them up to the brain. How would something like this be accomplished? The brain has an awareness of the sensory objects, but it shouldn't be able to instantiate them - this is only for the peripheral nervous system. So how to call functions on those sensor objects, from the brain via the spinal cord, to the peripheral nervous system and finally to the sensor in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the best solution would be to use:

- .NET remoting (pretty old) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.100).aspx
- Windows Communication Foundation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx

Brain will hold sensory objects which in fact (going back to programming language) will be transparent proxies to real sensory objects residing in a nervous system.

I'm not sure whether spinal cord fits into WCF/.NET Remoting architecture but one could consider it a communication channel which will be employed by the mentioned technologies.

Comment: A possible solution, though I'm concerned with the overhead in a rather bulky WCF contract. The primary concern is that the system should be pluggable, so that one may add and remove sensors on demand - I'm not sure WCF is at ease with dependency injections of further contracts, as additional sensors are added on the fly?

Comment: I'm no expert in WCF, but guys in Castle Project did an awesome job integrating WCF with their IoC container: http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.WCF-Integration-Facility.ashx?HL=wcf

Answer (score 0):

In Java you could do something like this with RMI. In C# please take a look at CORBA.

Doing things like this with a tcp/ip-server (I guess you want to open a socket and then parse command through it) is pain in the neck. If you want to do this else, you have to define Commands which are sended, received, parsed and the right method is called.

If you are able to set up sth. like a IIS you could probably write a Webservice in C#. The Actors would consume the Methods of the Webservice and "remotely" call them.

Comment: Hello Benni, good input, the define commands-way is probably a good way to go. The brain has knowledge of the sensor objects and could instantiate ICommand objects and serialize these and send them through the spine tcp/ip server towards the peripheral nervous system controller, responsible for distributing them to the relevant sensors for execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understood your question, but, can't you serialize your commands and send them through your sockets?

An easier approach would be a [self hosted wcf service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx), as it will free you from implementing communication details.